# Optional Parameters with method overloding

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

I have a method like that :

```
public static void Fill<T> (this DropDownList control,
   Expression<Func<T, object>> value,      
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause = null,
   Expression<Func<T, object>> orderClause = null,
   string selectedvalue = null) where T : class
{}
```

So far so good...
But I need add List option to Where and Order clause, so I added more 3 new methods:

```
public static void Fill<T> (this DropDownList control,
   Expression<Func<T, object>> value,      
   IList<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> listWhereClause = null,
   IList<Expression<Func<T, object>>> listOrderClause = null,
   string selectedvalue = null) where T : class
{}

public static void Fill<T> (this DropDownList control,
   Expression<Func<T, object>> value,      
   IList<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> listWhereClause = null,
   Expression<Func<T, object>>> orderClause = null,
   string selectedvalue = null) where T : class
{}

public static void Fill<T> (this DropDownList control,
   Expression<Func<T, object>> value,      
   Expression<Func<T, bool>>> whereClause = null,
   IList<Expression<Func<T, object>>> listOrderClause = null,
   string selectedvalue = null) where T : class
{}
```

The problem is now I got Ambiguous Invocation error... 
How is the best option to solve that (without increase the method count)?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just generate the queries by having the callers call `Select`, `Where`, `OrderBy`, etc. on their own?  Why grab all of the expressions like this instead?  Seems like it's more trouble than it's worth, and will dramatically decrease readability in the process.

Comment: 1. There is no C# 4.5, you're probably confusing C# 5.0 and .Net 4.5. 2. This is not specific to C# 5.0, optional parameters were added in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove default values (`null`) for your overloads. Because you've added overload with default `null` values compiler simply don't know which one to use.

Comment: The other option is to (don't shoot me) typecast the nulls, eg. `(Expression<Func<T, bool>>>)null`

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you shouldn't really be using null collections in general; you'd want empty collections instead.

Comment: But the order and where clauses must be optional ... To remove that, I need to create several others overloding methods, right?

Comment: @Paul it all depends, there're certainly too many mixed things there (at least for me): couple (similar) overload with many optional parameters. Consider this method call: `DropDownList.Fill<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>>, IList<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>)` Which one should be used in this case (1st or 2nd overload)?

Comment: @Paul think about use cases and differences between arguments, then refactor your methods. You can always provide more general method, which could be used within more specialized ones